# R - convert datatype of all columns in a dataframe from character to numeric dynamically

Tags: r

I have around 200 columns in my dataframe.
I am looking to convert the columns that has a data type of char into factors and then to levels or integers.

For example , Man becoming 1.

The below code works manually,

```
as.factor(df$colName1)
as.integer(df$colName1)
```

But how can we make that check for all columns using a loop and then convert it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- apply(df,2,function(x){
      if(is.character(x)){
         x <- as.factor(x)
         levels(x) <- 1:length(levels(x))
         return(x)  
      }
})
## I believe that this should work
```

Comment: No, it says object X not found and also it says there is an Unexpected '{'. Kindly advise.

Comment: I forgot to close if sentence, try now

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, the syntax would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate_if(is.character, funs(as.integer(factor(.))))
```